# Find substrings with multiple newline characters in string using Regex

Tags: c#, regex

I need to use regular expression to this string:

---

"\r\n+CMGL: 0,\"REC READ\",\"+79119968091\",,\"13/10/28,15:22:36+16\"\r\n10160008\r\n$GPMC,081915,A,5614.6801,N,04359.0266,E,0.0,190.2,121109,,*19\r\n+CMGL: 1,\"REC READ\",\"+79119968091\",,\"13/10/28,15:34:26+16\"\r\n#ALARM! \r\n10160008\r\n$GPMC,081915,A,5614.6801,N,04359.0266,E,0.0,190.2,121109,,*19\r\n\r\nOK\r\n"

---

I need to get 2 substrings(every substring starts with *\r\n+CMGL:* and ends with *\r\n*) from string above:

1. \r\n+CMGL: 0,\"REC READ\",\"+79119968091\",,\"13/10/28,15:22:36+16\"\r\n10160008\r\n$GPMC,081915,A,5614.6801,N,04359.0266,E,0.0,190.2,121109,,*19\r\n
2. \r\n+CMGL: 1,\"REC READ\",\"+79119968091\",,\"13/10/28,15:34:26+16\"\r\n#ALARM! \r\n10160008\r\n$GPMC,081915,A,5614.6801,N,04359.0266,E,0.0,190.2,121109,,*19\r\n

I have this regular expression

```
Regex r = new Regex(@"\+CMGL: (\d+),""(.+)"",""(.+)"",(.*),""(.+)""(\r\n((.|\n)*)\r\n\b)");
```

This regular expression works good but **not** for last group (\r\n((.|\n)*)\r\n\b). Problem is that i don't know how much *\r\n* symbols string will have until I see start of new substring (*\r\n+CMGL:* ).
Thank in advance

Comment: You may find this useful: http://gskinner.com/RegExr/

Answer (score 2):

For Starting with  **\r\n+CMGL:** and ending with **\r\n** you can use below regular expression :

```
\\r\\n\+CMGL:.*?\*19\\r\\n
```

Comment: Thank you for answer, but read please my question one more time. Substring starts with '\r\n+CMGL:' and ends with '\r\n', but it can contains a lot of '\r\n' symbols inside, and I don't know how much it is.

Comment: yes. so this regular expression will take the string starting from \r\n+CMGL: and consider the next \r\n.

Comment: It returns +CMGL: 0,\"REC READ\",\"+79119968091\",,\"13/10/28,15:22:36+16\"\r\n10160008\r\n but not +CMGL: 0,\"REC READ\",\"+79119968091\",,\"13/10/28,15:22:36+16\"\r\n10160008\r\n$GPMC,081915,A,5614.6801,N,04359.0266,E,0.0,190.2,121109,,*19\r\n

Comment: in your string what if we make a regular expression which starts from '\r\n+CMGL:' and ends with '*19\r\n' ? if *19\r\n is fixed